# sending/receiving on specific port of bridge

Tags: networking, ethernet, vlan

We have an board containing an embedded switch. These devices are supposed to be used in a ERPS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_Ring_Protection_Switching) setup, while also allowing auxiliary devices (e.g. laptops, display units etc.) to be attached to the remaining ports on the switch.

Previously, the devices used a linux kernel with a lot of out-of-tree patches for supporting the switch. Now, we're trying to use the switchdev framework, i.e. create a bridge and use the `ip` and `bridge` commands to handle vlan membership etc. However, the ERPS logic still needs to be able to send packets out of and receive packets on specific ports, in order to know when a link in the ring gets broken and the redundant link needs to be unblocked.

We use LLDP to know which neighbors consist of a device that's part of the ring protocol, and which neighbors are just auxilliary devices - this also matters for the vlan membership rules.

So, we have ports lan1, lan2, lan3, lan4, a bridge (lanx) created with

```
ip link add name lanx type bridge vlan_default_pvid 0
ip link set dev lan1 master lanx
...
ip link set dev lan4 master lanx
bridge vlan add dev lanx vid 1 self
bridge vlan add dev lanx vid 3 self
ip link add link lanx name lanx.1 type vlan id 1
ip link add link lanx name lanx.3 type vlan id 3
```

and to implement the ERPS, we also have vlan 3 sub-interfaces of each lan1,...,lan4:

```
ip link add link lan1 name lan1.3 type vlan id 3
...
```

All ports are supposed to be members of vlan1, while only ports connected to other devices with a switch are members of vlan3. When LLDP discovers such a neighbor, or perhaps two neighbors, an erps instance is started on, say, lan1.3 and lan3.3.

And everything works just fine; all the devices work together to block one and only one port; unplugging a cable the devices figure out to unblock that port so traffic continues flowing. That is, traffic on VLAN1. It seems that VLAN3 traffic doesn't work at all; pinging the IPv6LL address of another device using "ping $ip%lanx.3" fails, while "ping $ip%lanx.1" works just fine. And it's perhaps not that surprising; tcpdump seems to suggest that the pings do reach lan1.3 of the other device (not lanx.3), which answers, and the answer reaches lan2.3 of the first device. Indeed, "ping $ip%lan2.3" does seem to work - and we already know that the erps logic communicates just fine over those lanN.3 subdevices.

So either we need to drop the lan1.3 subdevices and make our erps program able to use lanx.3, but somehow ensuring that the continuity messages are sent out of (and received from) specific ports - is that possible? Or, we need to instruct the kernel to not send all vlan3 traffic received on lan1 into lan1.3 only, but also let it reach the bridge device (preferably with some filtering so only the continuity messages are handled by lan1.3).